# How to run the ml kit samples on Android Studio virtual or physical devices

Tags: android, google-mlkit

Maybe this is a really newbie question, here it is:
I downloaded the ml kit samples from github into Android Studio via the project from version control option.
I cannot really run it either on a virtual of physical device.
When I want to run it it asks to "add configuration".
On the left to the run button (the one right of the physical device) I have the "add configuration " button and when I do that i get the "Error: Run configuration Unnamed is not supported in the curent project. Cannot obtain the package." error. The module is chosen  "mlkit".
I googled left and right but no answer.
Thank you.

I tried running on the virtual or physical devices, tried adding a new configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the samples from https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit ?

You should be able to open the project by Android Studio, e.g. https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart, and build the app then run on device